# Can transitive graphs have non-integer growth dimension?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, graph-theory

Say we have some transitive (edge and vertex) graph $G$ s.t $|B(v,n)| \leq c n^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\geq 0$.

Polynomial growth/dimension in this setting meaning that for some $d\geq 0$ we can pick two constants $a,b$ s.t $an^d\leq |B(v,n)| \leq bn^d$ for every integer $n$. Is it always the case that $d$ will be an integer when $G$ is transitive?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to your question in **N.  Seifter**, *Properties of Graphs with Polynomial Growth* (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589569190064Q)

> [speaking about Gromov result on groups of polynomial growth] here always exist constants $c_l$, $c_2$ such that $c_1n^d \leq f_G(n) \leq  c_2n^d$ holds for some integer $d$. We call this well-defined integer the growth degree $d_G$ of $G$. A deep result of Trofimov (see [19, Theorem 2]) implies that the same also holds for the growth functions of graphs with polynomial growth.

sadly I could not get access to the english version of **V.I. TROFIMOV**, *Graphs with polynomial growth*, so I cannot elaborate, but this is apparently an highly non-trivial fact.

Comment: appreciate it! interesting result.

Comment: "[...] same also holds for the growth functions of graphs with polynomial growth." It appears a "vertex-transitive" is missing from this sentence (but it is missing in the original article as well).

Comment: I added an answer with the theorems of Trofimov. I do not immediately see how they achieve the claimed integer exponent, but I also don't know too much about groups.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the statement of the two main theorems from V. I. Trofimov, *"Graphs with polynomial growth"* mentioned in [thibo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4039892/415941).
I don't see immediately how this yields the claimed integer exponent, but perhaps someone can explain.

[image]